# Cannot find pom.xml file inside allure reporter folder

Tags: maven, plugins, protractor, report, allure

I am trying to generate html reports out of allure results using mvn command. As per the documentation, it needs `pom.xml` file inside `node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter` folder.

I saw many tutorials but when i go to that folder, `pom.xml` is not there. Please direct me with correct steps.

Comment: What steps are you following? What tutorial did you use? Please provide concrete elements. You may want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am doing following Steps : 1. Generated allure results , i am copying to jasmine-allure-reporter folder. 2. Executing mvn site command in command prompt.  I referred udemy protractor tutorials for this one and in video pom.xml already there. Please direct me with correct steps.

Comment: Instead of adding missing information via comments, please edit your question and add the information there. Also there is no need to add "edit" - it is fine to pretend that you added all required information right from the start :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem.

create a pom.xml file and put this inside it,this is the file you would generate after npm install, but it is not generating more

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>protractor-allure-plugin-generate-html</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <allure.version>1.4.15</allure.version>
        <allure.maven.version>2.2</allure.maven.version>
        <!-- Relative to the dir you're running from -->
        <allure.results_pattern>allure-results</allure.results_pattern>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-report-face</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>target/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>2299</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resultsPattern>${allure.results_pattern}</resultsPattern>
                    <!--<reportVersion>1.4.15</reportVersion>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation references a ready-to-use `pom.xml` file. But this is removed as part of [this code commit](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine/commit/cbd72529ec95781e2f6f97c05a77c6e31dde6381)

We can generate allure report by using **`Allure Command Line Tool`**

You can add that dependency in your current project by running the following npm command

`npm install allure-commandline --save-dev`

After this, add a `"posttest":"allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report"` part in the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file.

When you are running the test by using `npm test`, the command mentioned in `posttest` will execute and generate the report in the report directory.

```
  "scripts": {
      "pretest": "rm -rf allure-report",
      "test": "protractor conf.js",
      "posttest": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report || true"
  }
```

The `pretest` section is removing previously generated test result folder.

Sometimes `npm test` doesn't trigger `posttest` section when it failed. Added bash `||` operator in the `posttest` section to avoid this.